# CodeIgniter Ion Auth not sending activation email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, ion-auth

I have CodeIgniter Ion Auth configured with the following smtp info:

```
$config['use_ci_email'] = FALSE;
$config['email_config'] = array(
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'mail.example.com',
    'smtp_user' => 'support@example.com', // actual values different
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'smtp_port' => '26'
);
```

When I register for an account, Ion Auth simply says "Activation email sent" but I see nothing in my inbox (checked spam folder too). I checked the info with a SMTP testing tool, and the SMTP info provided in `$config['email_config']` is correct. I followed the Ion Auth documentation, but I am not receiving any emails. Is there anything else that needs to be done? Thanks!

Comment: Setting `$config['use_ci_email']` to TRUE and configuring CodeIgniter's Email class did the trick.

Comment: you must be checking it on localhost. Emails are not sent on localhost unless configured

Comment: @raheelshan what on earth does that mean? :)

Comment: @RobertGrant install [this](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) and it will work.

Comment: Are you trying to say that if you point at localhost to send mails and there's no mailserver on localhost, it won't work? If so, why are you specifying localhost in particular, as that applies to any hostname. Did you originally mean: "check there's a mailserver on the server and port you're pointing to."

Comment: i am facing the same problem in server , after registration ,it says Activation Email Sent, but i have not received  any email, what are the changes you have made...

Mysettings are as follows
$config['use_ci_email']             = FALSE; 
$config['email_activation']        = TRUE;             
$config['manual_activation']     = FALSE;

Comment: if i set
$config['use_ci_email'] = TRUE;
i get Unable to Send Activation Email

Answer (score 4):

Check for

```
$config['email_activation'] = TRUE; // Email Activation for registration
$config['manual_activation'] = FALSE;
```

is configured or not??

Go to `config/ion_auth.php`, make sure `$config['use_ci_email']` is set to `TRUE`.

Comment: for this to work, one should store its email configs in a file 'email.php' in config folder.

Answer (score 4):

Mine worked with some minor changes...like:

in library go to `ion_auth`: add the `set_newline("\r\n")`:

[image]

also in config folder go to ion_auth and your email configuration should look like :

[image]

But remember the `set_newline()` is very very important

Answer (score 0):

This will work, its what am using on my system in one of the controllers..

=========

## ========USING GMAIL

```
public function sendmail($data=array())
{


    $config = Array(

    'protocol' => 'smtp',

    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',

    'smtp_port' => 465,

    'smtp_user' => 'emailaddress@gmail.com',

    'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxx',

    'mailtype'  => 'html', 

    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',

    'wordwrap'   =>TRUE

);


$this->load->library('email',$config); // Note: no $config param needed

    //$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('emailaddress@gmail.com', 'Test Mailer');

$this->email->to('receiver@gmail.com');

$this->email->subject('Test email from CI and Gmail');

$this->email->message('This is a test, using CodeIgniter Email Class.');

$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


 if ($this->email->send()) {

     echo 'Your email was sent, thanks.';

  } else {

     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. i hope it will help you.

```
$config['email_smtp'] = TRUE;
$config['email_from'] = 'mail.example.com';
$config['email_from_name'] = 'mail';
$config['admin_email'] = 'mail.example.com';
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";

/**
 * SMTP Settings
 */
if ($config['email_smtp'] === TRUE) {
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'support@example.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '5';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'mail.example.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
}
```

Comment: Whereabouts do you add this?